# Selenium: is there any way to find an element that has nothing inside?

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'd like to find an element that has nothing inside.
For example:

```
<div class="top">
 selection: 
 <b></b>
</div>
```

It displays like this:

selection:

In this HTML code, `<b></b>` has nothing inside. But for testing purpose, I want to find it without text inside.
I tried
`findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'top')]/b[text()=='']")`
but it didn't return anything.
Is there a way to locate `<b></b>`?

Comment: can you share the more relevant HTML or the link?

Comment: This won't help to make your XPath work, but FYI if you want to evaluate text equality use `text() = ''` not `text() == ''`

Comment: The important thing to understand is that the `b` element doesn't have any text node children, so looking for something with a text node equal to "" isn't going to work. This is one of many reasons we recommend using "." rather than "text()" - the expression `//b[.=""]` will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. Can I ask what "." means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `text()` matcher.

```
//div[contains(@class,'top')]/b
```

Will match the `<b>`

Alternatively:

```
//div[contains(@class,'top')]/b[not(text())]
```

Comment: //div[contains(@class,'top')]/b[not(text())] This one works, thank you very much for your quick response!